# NavigatorUserMediaError: TrackStartError

Tags: html, getusermedia

I've been using an application that I made for the last month. It uses the getUserMedia() feature of the HTML5.

As of 2 days, without me doing ANYTHING with the code the camera stopped working.
At first I solved by getting a extra camera that I have but that stopped working too.

The problem happens in Chrome only and in several different computers so I am pretty sure it isn't a specific driver issue.

Firefox is working but it doesn't suit me at the moment because I have not yet developed some multi-browser support.

The error I receive is:

```
NavigatorUserMediaError
   constraintName: ""
   message: ""
   name: "TrackStartError"
   __proto__: NavigatorUserMediaError
```

I haven't made any code changes in the last days at all so it would be introduced bug by my part.

I am just using VIDEO and no audio and my query looks something like this:

```
 navigator.getUserMedia({
            video : {
                mandatory : {
                    minWidth : 480,
                    minHeight : 640,
                    maxWidth : 480,
                    maxHeight : 640
                }
            }
        }, function(stream) {
            localMediaStream = stream;
            camSuccess();
        }, errorCallback);
```

the width and height trick was to ensure I get the proportions I wanted... and it was also functional.

I appreciatte any help/suggestions to debug this...

Cheers

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43945050/813988)