# What is a TrackStartError?

Tags: javascript, audio, webrtc, getusermedia

I am running audio only sessions using the constraints:

```
  var constraints = {
    audio: {
      mandatory: {
        echoCancellation: false
      }, optional: [{
        sourceId: audioSource
      }]
    },
    video: false
  };
```

I am noticing that in a very small number of sessions I am receiving a TrackStartError from the getUserMedia request.  I cannot see any correlation between browser/browser version/OS/devices available. Some computers continually get this error, some once and then after a new getUserMedia request no problem and some don't experience this at all.

Is the TrackStartError documented fully as I have seen some issues around mandatory audio flags, but echoCancellation seems not to have this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`TrackStartError` is a [non-spec Chrome-specific](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=651910#c17) version of [`NotReadableError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia#Errors):

> Although the user granted permission to use the matching devices, a hardware error occurred at the operating system, browser, or Web page level which prevented access to the device.

Seems fitting, given that your constraints are [non-spec and Chrome-specific](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28911694/918910) as well. Instead, try:

```
  var constraints = {
    audio: {
      echoCancellation: { exact: false },
      deviceId: audioSource
    },
  };
```

I highly recommend the official [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) polyfill to [deal with such browser differences](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter/pull/530#issue-227729332).

Some systems (like Windows) give exclusive access to hardware devices, which can cause this error if other applications are currently using a mic or camera. It can also be a bug or driver issue.

Comment: I'm seeing `TrackStartError` being thrown by Chrome on Windows when the webcam is already in use by another app, Chrome tabs can share the same webcam though. Firefox throws `NotReadableError` even when another FFox tab is using the webcam. Firefox will also throw it on macOS.