# Error "TrackStartError" in CefSharp-based application

Tags: c#, cefsharp, getusermedia

I create a sipphone using CefSharp and WPF. Until some time everything worked, but today I got the error "TrackStartError", although I did not change anything in the code. I checked to see if this works in "CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf" and it does not work there either. However, in the browser Chrome still works.

For verification, I performed in the console CefSharp Devtools:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49iSX.png)

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919639/what-is-a-trackstarterror) it is said that "at the level of the operating system, browser or web page, there was a hardware error that prevented access to the device." What could be the reason for this? And how to fix it?

If this is due to the fact that some application has seized control of the microphone, how I can determine this application?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the problem. In my case, the microphone was blocked by an antivirus (Kaspersky endpoint security).After disabling it, the error disappeared.